# MacOS Sierra multiple uTun devices but why?

Tags: networking, macos-sierra, ifconfig

Using the command ifconfig I am seeing 2 uTun devices being used. I reboot and they are both present. One even has set the mtu to 2000. Does this mean im infected with malware? I am not running any applications at the time of running ifconfig. The activity monitor does not show anything that jumps out either.

```
utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 2000
  inet6 fe80::1xx5:d7x8:1x6:6x3x%utun0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xa 
  nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun1: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1380
  inet6 fe80::9x3e:9x26:bx10:9x72%utun1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xb 
  inet6 fdf6:d47w:rrr5:4424:9x5x:xa26:bx10:9472 prefixlen 64 
  nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be fine, mtu is just the Maximum Transmission Unit, you can manually set it to something between around 100 and 9000. utun is the renamed TUN interface from apple, just have a look on wikipedia to tun. Probably used for your connection to the iCloud (back to my mac).
they should vanish if you turn off wifi/unplug the ethernet wire..

Caution: I am not an expert in this, just the regular geek :-)